# Error on execution of rfe function prior to running NaiveBayes

Tags: r, r-caret, naivebayes, rfe

When I execute rfe for feature selection prior to executing NaiveBayes,

```
library(caret)
tc_data_final <- nearZeroVar(tc_data_final,saveMetrics = TRUE)
tc_data_final[tc_data_final[,"zerovar"] > 0, ]
set.seed(1)
ldaProfile <- rfe(tc_data_final, tc_data_final$Cancelled,
                    rfeControl = rfeControl(functions = ldaFuncs, method = "cv"))
```

I get the below error

```
Error in { : 
  task 1 failed - "variables  30  83 109 appear to be constant within groups"
```

As you can see I did eliminate all NULL variance variables then what other reasons could be for the error. Any help is highly appreciated.

FYI.: tc_data_final has 179 variables with 164,000 observations.

Any other pointers for other feature selection options before I execute NaiveBayes also would be very helpful.

Comment: Actually, in the code you provide you are not removing all NULL variances. You are just printing them. If you want to remove them, you need `tc_data_final <- tc_data_final[tc_data_final[,"zerovar"] > 0, ]`

Comment: oh that I did manually from the file. Have got the answer will post separately